# What algorithms do GMail/Facebook use to serve context relevant ads?

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, text-processing, sentiment-analysis

GMail serves some really good ads on the column on the right of the email text. Same goes for Facebook. The ads which I see on Facebook are often (very) relevant to what interests me. Obviously they preprocess the information available to them. GMail scans the text of my email, extracts keywords and then serves relevant ads. The same goes for Facebook. They have a lot of user specific information available to them. So I would imagine they preprocess all of it, before generating any ad recommendations.

Does anyone know of what specific algorithms do those systems use?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook, at least, doesn't seem to do any context analysis. Instead, when you buy an ad, you select who will see it based on their location, age, pages... and Facebook will try to show your ad to all those people (ads for a given person are sorted based on how much the advertiser wishes to pay to display it, and only the first few ads are shown).

Try [creating an ad](http://www.facebook.com/ads/create/), it's extremely interesting (and you can get pretty far before they ask you for your credit card number).